# Transaction by receipt number

Tags: api, transactions, square-connect, receipt

I looked through the Squareup.com API v2 for a method to retrieve a transaction using the receipt number on the printed receipt (It is 4 characters) but I found nothing documented for this method.

Is this possible?

I know I can get the transaction details using transaction ID but that's not what I want.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this a little more?

Comment: I've built a reward/point app where I want to let customers who bought from the store to enter the Receipt ID in the app and be rewarded with points based on the receipt's amount if is confirmed valid. Currently, we let the customer hand over the receipt to the cashier where he/she enters the reward points manually into the backend. I want to make the process easy and fast without the need for cashier involvement. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot query the API by receipt number at this time.

If you needed to look up by receipt number, you could keep a separate store of the receipts indexed by the receipt code, but that might be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: In the dashboard, I can query the search using the receipt number. I don't think this should be excluded from the API?

Answer (score 0):

The 4-digit receipt ID you are referring to is the same as the first four characters of the selected tender ID for the transaction. You could accomplish this by retrieving all transactions for the given location and searching the first four characters. You may need additional details, such as the payment total to guarantee against duplicates.

Comment: Yes, that was an approach I thought of but it is a long way to do it.